# What is the difference between SQLEXPRESS and MSSQLSERVER?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, when I looked into the services for SQL Server I saw there are two different services with different instances.

1. `SQLEXPRESS`
2. `MSSQLSERVER`

Can anyone help me to get clear the difference between #1 and #2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In VS2010 you will access the instance with localhost/SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install multiple copies of SQL Server onto the same machine. To keep them apart, all "copies" (called **instances**) except the first (default) one have to be named.

So by default, when you install your first instance of SQL Server, you won't give it any instance name - it'll be the default instance that you connect to use the server name of `.`, `(local)` or your machine name (or IP address).

Any further instance you want to install needs to get a separate, unique instance name.

Visual Studio will by default install SQL Server Express onto your machine (unless you explicitly tell it not to), and that will be called the `SQLEXPRESS` instance on your machine (hence the service name also is called `SQLEXPRESS`). You connect to that named instance using `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXRPESS`.

So most likely, in your case, you installed a "full" version of SQL Server onto your machine (as the default instance - service is called `MSSQLSERVER`), and Visual Studio installed a second copy of SQL Server - an Express version - as `SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 0):

MSSQLSERVER is the default instance (accessed via `localhost`) and SQLEXPRESS is a named instance (accessed by `localhost/SQLEXPRESS`)

Did you install twice?

Comment: no i just wanted to know when i install VS2010 he will allow me to create tables etc.. in Data Source. so what instance he will creates.
if i installed VS2010.